# Symfony Validation: Error message not showing at associated field

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

**Symfony 5.2.5**

**Minified code**

```
//Entities
class Article {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ArticleTranslation::class, mappedBy="article", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $translations;
}

class ArticleTranslation {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Article::class, inversedBy="translations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $locale;
}


//FormTypes
class ArticleType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(/*other fields*/)
            ->add('translations', ArticleTranslationType::class, ['label' => false, 'data' => new ArticleTranslation(), 'mapped' => false])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Save']);

        $builder->get('translations')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
           $entity = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData();
           $translation = $event->getData();
           $translation->setLocale($this->localeService->getCurrentLocale()); //custom service returns e.g. "en"
           $entity->addTranslation($translation);
        });
    }
}

class ArticleTranslationType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('body', TextareaType::class);
    }
}
```

I have two entities called `Article` and `ArticleTranslation` with a OneToMany relationship. When creating an `Article` I want to add a `ArticleTranslation` to it (e.g. English) - that way there is atleast 1 translation provided. The Article itself just stores generic data like publish-date, while the translation stores title and the content (called body). The above code works fine my only issue is following:

When the validation for `title` or `body` fails, the error message is shown above the formular, instead of right next to the associated field. Every other field correctly has the error message right next to it. I am using the default bootstrap 4 form theme.

How can I move the error message to the correct field? The Symfony profiler returns that `data.translations[0].body` should not be null (since its a collection it has an index) - I guess I need somehow make that into `data.translations.body` for it to work?

---

**Temporary fix:** When adding the validation inside my `ArticleTranslationType` & remove the `Assert\Valid` constraint it works. Still interested in another solution with my provided code - Thanks

Comment: Which version of symfony you have?  Also, it will be helpful if you share the twig part

Comment: Symfony 5.2.5 - twig is just a generic form rendering `{{ form(form) }}`. The form theme is the default symfony one https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around I finally got my solution. Since the validation tries to validate the first element in my collection e.g. `data.translations[0].body` I needed just to provide the correct property path for it to know.

```
$builder->add(
  'translations', ArticleTranslationType::class, array(
    'data' => new ArticleTranslation(),
    'mapped' => false,
    'label' => false,
    'property_path' => 'translations[0]' //first element of collection
  )
);
```

This maps the error messages to the corresponding field.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the [error_bubbling](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling) FormType field option.

### error_bubbling

**type**: `boolean` **default**: `false` unless the form is compound.

*If `true`, any errors for this field will be passed to the parent field or form. For example, if set to `true` on a normal field, any errors for that field will be attached to the main form, not to the specific field.*

---

Your **ArticleTranslationType** is `compound`, therefore **error_bubbling** defaults to `true`.
The following should do the trick.

```php
$builder->add(
  'translations', ArticleTranslationType::class, array(
    'data' => new ArticleTranslation(),
    'error_bubbling' => false,
    'mapped' => false,
    'label' => false
  )
);
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, sadly it does not seem to work the way I want it to be. When setting `error_bubbling` to `false` it does indeed not write the error message above the form *but* it does write it above the `ArticleTranslationType` and not to the corresponding field. For example when I do not provide any value for `body` the error message shows above my `title` field (since they are both in their own FormType).

Comment: Quick update: I got my solution by providing `property_path` for my `translations`. I will make a answer for other people having same issues. Thanks again :)

Comment: Using the `property_path` is not really a solution as it will still fail when adding more than a single translation to an article. Basically, you want to set `error_bubbling` to `false`, to any compound forms, especially if they're nested. In addition, you should take a look at the `CollectionType` for handling your `OneToMany` association in a form.

Comment: thanks for your answer. In my case there will only be 1 translation added each time - that was my goal. I skipped the `CollectionType` on purpose. With my current solution it works when creating `Article` with a default `ArticleTranslation` and also when adding new `ArticleTranslations ` (just a form with ArticleTranslationType) later on.